# Find an idempotent operator with $\ell_\infty$ as its range?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm not sure how to show the following question:

Let ${X}$ be a Banach space that contains $\ell_\infty$ as a closed subspace. Prove there exists an idempotent bounded linear functional $E$ on ${X}$ with range $\ell_\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to work with a more general statement: if $Y$ is a   subspace of a Banach space $X$, then every bounded operator $T:Y\to \ell_\infty$ extends to a bounded operator $\widetilde T:X\to\ell_\infty$.

Proof: use Hahn-Banach coordinate-wise. As a bonus, you get $\|\widetilde T\|=\|T\|$. $\quad \Box$

To obtain the statement in your question, let $Y=\ell_\infty\subset X$, and $T$ the identity map.

---

Remark: the above property of $\ell_\infty$ is expressed by saying that it's an *injective* Banach space.